# Remove Punctuation characters at last from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string value and punctuation string. I need to remove punctuation characters from a string value from the last till it finds the character except punctuation character. Here is a sample string of Input value and punctuation characters to remove.

**Sample Input String**

```
1. The Indian economy.My suggestion.,..,... ...

2. The Indian economy.,,[], ..My suggestion.,..,... ...[]
```

**Punctuation characters to be removed**

```
[,.;:]
```

**Result String after replace**

```
1. The Indian economy.My suggestion

2. The Indian economy.,,[], ..My suggestion
```

Any help to this will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [String.TrimEnd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string result=str.TrimEnd('.',',','[',']',' ');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following pattern to match trailing punctuation characters:

```
@"\W+$"
```

---

```
string str = @"1. The Indian economy.My suggestion.,..,... ...";
string replaced = Regex.Replace(str, @"\W+$", "");
Console.WriteLine(replaced); // => 1. The Indian economy.My suggestion
```

`\W` matches non-word characters.